# R - Party package: is cforest really bagging?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, party

I'm using the "party" package to create random forest of regression trees.
I've created a ForestControl class in order to limit my number of trees (ntree), of nodes (maxdepth) and of variables I use to fit a tree (mtry).
One thing I'm not sure of is if the cforest algo is using subsets of my training set for each tree it generates or not.

I've seen in the documentation that it is bagging so I assume it should. But I'm not sure to understand well what the "subset" input is in that function.

I'm also puzzled by the results I get using ctree: when plotting the tree, I see that all my variables of my training set are classified in the different terminal tree nodes while I would have exepected that it only uses a subset here too.

So my question is, is cforest doing the same thing as ctree or is it really bagging my training set?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Ben